# When declaring or defining a cursor in a package specification, is there a way to avoid the definition of a record type?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, record, rowtype

My employer uses an application which stores metadata about business cases in a master table and some 40 detail tables.

Currently, I maintain a package which reads from these tables and generates for each master record a file with HTML output.

My package body contains the following:

```
type output_text_type is table of varchar(32768);
function fA(mri in master_record_identifier_type)
        return output_text_type
is
cursor cA(if1 master_record_identifier_type.if1%type, ...)
is
select tA.f1, tA.f2, ...
from tA
where tA.if1 = if1
...;
begin -- fA
        ...
        for r in cA(mri.if1, mri.if2, ...) loop
           <generate HTML using r.f1, r.rf2, mri.if1...>
        end loop;
end fA;
... some 40 more function with the same structure ...
```

BTW, most cursors return less than 100 records (most often zero or one), so `fetch ... bulk collect ...` would not result in a performance gain.

Now we plan to exchange the business cases' metadata (and, of course, the documents themselves) with other organizations. To this end, we have to generate xml data structures with the -- in substance -- same content.

To fulfill this requirement, I plan to split my current package (influenced by the idea of the model-view-controller pattern) in a package pkg_cursors, a pkg_html and a (yet to be written) pkg_xml.

Alas, I found only a working solution by defining a record as in:

```
create or replace package pkg_cursors
as
type rA is record(
       if1 tA.if1%type,
       f1  tA.f1%type, 
       f2  tA.f2%type,
       ... a dozen more fields ...
       );
cursor ca(master_record_identifier_type.if1%type, ...)
     return rA;
...
```

This is unfortunate, for until now adding a column to a table
resulted in an update of the cursor's select clause and adding the new column to the cursor-for-loop.  From now on, I have a third place to consider: the record definition.

I experimented also with cursors in the package spec:

```
create package pkg_cursors
as
cursor cA(...) is
select <select-list>
from ... where ...
return cA%rowtype;
```

but I got compilation errors.

Thus, my question is: Is there a way to avoid the record definition for the cursor return argument?

Do you think there is a better way to split the package?

(Please apologize my language faults and the length of this question. Would my command of the English language be more solid, this question would possibly be shorter.)

Comment: have you considered dynamic html? dbms_sql can do this (see dbms_sql.describe_columns)

Answer (score 1):

a dynamic SQL sample if its any help to your problem? doesn't have to be pipelined of course, i just did it that way.

```
SQL> create table one (id number, foo varchar2(20), if1 number);

Table created.

SQL> create table two (id number, foo varchar2(20), foo2 date, if1 number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into one values(1, 'test', 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into one values(1, 'test again', 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into two values(1, '2nd table', sysdate-1, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into two values(1, '2nd table - 2', sysdate-10, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into two values(1, '2nd table - 3', sysdate-3, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> create type vc_tab as table of varchar2(4000);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace function gen_html(p_tab in varchar2, p_master_id in number)
  2  return vc_tab
  3  pipelined
  4  is
  5    v_cur           integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  6    v_col_val       varchar2(4000);
  7    v_col_val_clob  clob;
  8    v_status        integer;
  9    v_desc_tbl      dbms_sql.desc_tab;
 10    v_col_cnt       number;
 11    v_row           varchar2(4000);
 12  begin
 13    execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'' ';
 14    execute immediate 'alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format=''dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ssxff tzh:tzm''';
 15    execute immediate 'alter session set nls_timestamp_format=''dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ssxff''';
 16
 17    dbms_sql.parse(v_cur,  'select * from ' || dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(p_tab) || ' where if1 = :b1',
 18                   dbms_sql.native);
 19    dbms_sql.bind_variable(v_cur, 'b1', p_master_id);
 20    dbms_sql.describe_columns(v_cur, v_col_cnt, v_desc_tbl);
 21
 22    for i in 1 .. v_col_cnt
 23    loop
 24      if (v_desc_tbl(i).col_type = 109)
 25      then
 26        dbms_sql.define_column(v_cur, i, v_col_val_clob);
 27      else
 28        dbms_sql.define_column(v_cur, i, v_col_val, 4000);
 29      end if;
 30    end loop;
 31
 32    v_status := dbms_sql.execute(v_cur);
 33
 34    pipe row('<h1>' || p_tab || '</h1>');
 35    pipe row('<table>');
 36    while ( dbms_sql.fetch_rows(v_cur) > 0 )
 37    loop
 38      pipe row('<tr>');
 39      for i in 1 .. v_col_cnt
 40      loop
 41        if (v_desc_tbl(i).col_type = 109)
 42        then
 43          dbms_sql.column_value(v_cur, i, v_col_val_clob);
 44          pipe row('<td>' || v_desc_tbl(i).col_name || '</td><td>' || v_col_val_clob || '</td>');
 45        else
 46          dbms_sql.column_value(v_cur, i, v_col_val);
 47          pipe row('<td>' || v_desc_tbl(i).col_name || '</td><td>' || v_col_val || '</td>');
 48        end if;
 49      end loop;
 50      pipe row('</tr>');
 51    end loop;
 52    pipe row('</table>');
 53    dbms_sql.close_cursor(v_cur);
 54
 55  end;
 56  /

Function created.

SQL> select * from table(gen_html('ONE', 1));

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<h1>ONE</h1>
<table>
<tr>
<td>ID</td><td>1</td>
<td>FOO</td><td>test</td>
<td>IF1</td><td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ID</td><td>1</td>
<td>FOO</td><td>test again</td>
<td>IF1</td><td>1</td>
</tr>
</table>

13 rows selected.

SQL> select * from table(gen_html('TWO', 1));

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<h1>TWO</h1>
<table>
<tr>
<td>ID</td><td>1</td>
<td>FOO</td><td>2nd table</td>
<td>FOO2</td><td>08-nov-2012 18:37:36</td>
<td>IF1</td><td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ID</td><td>1</td>
<td>FOO</td><td>2nd table - 2</td>
<td>FOO2</td><td>30-oct-2012 18:37:36</td>
<td>IF1</td><td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ID</td><td>1</td>
<td>FOO</td><td>2nd table - 3</td>
<td>FOO2</td><td>06-nov-2012 18:37:36</td>
<td>IF1</td><td>1</td>
</tr>
</table>

21 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. Unfortunately, the example in my question is much simpler than the real package. Your solution would impose a  higher notational burden than an additional record definition.